# "Not reproducible" close vote shows different reason in tooltip

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, close-reasons, tooltips

When I vote to close a question as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo" and then mouse over the "Close(1)" link below the question the tooltip says

> You voted to close as 'Not suitable for this site'. 2 more votes from other users are needed to close this question.

Comment: No Repro/Typo is a sub-reason of *"A community-specific reason - This question doesn’t meet a Stack Overflow guideline."*, so it's not wrong

Answer (score 6):

All the close reasons under ***A community-specific reason*** are considered *Not suitable for this site*. So closing with any reason under it (Needs debugging details, Typo, etc.) will have the tooltip show just that.

Any other reason (Needs Focus, Details or clarity, etc.) will show the corresponding message in the tooltip. This division can be clearly seen by the filter in the close votes review queue:

[image]

Comment: Ah, okay. I was confusing "Not suitable for this site" with "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network", so it looked like an off-by-one error to me.

Comment: *"This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"* ***is*** *"Not suitable for this site"*. It is one of the reasons under ***A community-specific reason***... :)